# How to run clamd as a service on Centos 8

Tags: centos, clam

I have downloaded clamd (and clamav) and I'd like to run clamd with on-access scanning as a service with systemctl. Is this even possible on Centos 8? If not, is there a anticirus alternative which will allow me to scan files on access?

```html
Failed to start clamd.service: Unit clamd.service not found.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since CentOS 7.x, you need to use `systemd` to create a .service file for `clamd`.
Have you installed `clamav-server-systemd` package?? This should fix your problem..You could create your own if needed:

Check out https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files .

Comment: CentOS8 installs clamd.service automatically, when installing clamav. In CentOS8, you start giving an instance, e.g. "systemctl enable clamd@scan.service --now"